# How to revert column change in EF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

In EF4, I want to show a confirmation message when user changes a particular column, saying something like "Are you sure you want to change it?", Yes/No. I want to accept this change only if user presses Yes and revert it back to original value if he presses No. I'm trying to do this in the partial method On**Column**Changing (such as **OnStatusChanging**) generated by EF. The method provides me the new incoming value, but I don't know how to "cancel" it, something equivalent to `e.Handled = true`, or `e.Cancel = true`.

BTW, I'm following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/07/07/implementing-validation-in-wpf-on-entity-framework-entities.aspx) approach for validations/confirmations.

Comment: You tagged MVVM - are you sure you want to do this in the database layer and not in your viewmodel/view layer?  By the time you get to the OnChangingEvent it's really late to be aborting the change (it's already happening).  Depending on how you're binding - you could do an explicit trigger, or bind to the control's onchanging event.  Your EF entity shouldn't be doing user confirmations.  Your entity really shouldn't have any knowledge of how to call the view.

Comment: Right, I thought about that but there are two issues. One is that my VM exposes a public property of type List<Of SalesOrder>, to which my view is binding. Now this SalesOrder is a Model type (I decided against creating a carbon-copy of this type in the ViewModel layer and then doing manual cloning or AutoMapper stuff), so I really don't know which other place my validation/confirmation code should/can go. Secondly, I don't want to do it in View layer either, becuz this confirmation should occur for any kind of view we build on top of our VM, so listening to UI events is not an option either.

Comment: @MarkOreta: You may also want to see the link I added.